# Ubuntu showing "No space left on device" but I still have space

Tags: crash, disk, disk-usage, ext4, btrfs

I have Ubuntu installed on a Lenovo laptop with three partitions. The first partition is formatted with an ext4 file system and mounted at root `/`. It has 248GB of storage allocated to it. The second partition is formatted with the btrfs file system and mounted at `/home`. I also had 100GB of free space.

Last week my `/home` partition filled up so I created a new partition-formatted with btrfs and moved some files from the `/home` directory to it. This freed up about 50GB of space on the `/home` partition but my system has been crashing and certain operations are failing showing "no space left on device", but i still have 50GB free space on my `/home` partition.

I have tried checking to see if I ran out of inodes but I found out btrfs doesnt use inodes.

This is the output of running `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           767M  2.5M  764M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       137G   29G  101G  23% /
tmpfs           3.8G   89M  3.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /run/qemu
/dev/sda3       231G  173G   59G  75% /home
tmpfs           767M  2.5M  764M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Are you sure it it the `/home` partition that fails? Please add the output of `df -h` to your question.

Comment: i think so because the operations that give the error are operations in the /home partition and df -h shows that the /home partition is only 80% full.

Comment: Please add the output of `df` anyway. It tells us more than you have. Also add the output  of `mount`, thanks.

Comment: Also, "_certain operations_"? Please show us exactly what one operation is and it's output.

Comment: If you have chosen to set up a separate `/home` partition, then it won't share space with your root file system. Your root `/` can only use available space on its own partition. If you are getting free space errors, those errors are probably referring to your root partition. Partitioning creates inflexible artificial limits on how your system can utilize space. If you run out of space on one partition, you cannot borrow from another.

Comment: if i try to install something an error will popup telling me i have no space on the device. Also i am trying to paste the output of 'df'' but it isnt aligning well

Comment: ok thanks @Nmath. i just edited the post

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-05-04_Fixing-Btrfs-Filesystem-Full-Problems.html